# How to have identity map in doctrine ORM

Tags: php, design-patterns, orm, datamapper, identity-map

need to use a good PHP ORM that has elements of Datamapper and I am not clever enough to code it myself.

chosen doctrine, but  after reading through the user guide, cannot find anything that says how to use identity map to lower calls to database.

please show me how to have identity map in doctrine ORM?

just read and understood stuff like datamapper, activerecord, identity map, domain model YESTERDAY via fowler's PEAA book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [this article](http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns) Doctrine 2 supports the identity map pattern